# How do I resize my android emulator? software display is just on the top left corner the rest of the screen is just black

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation, mobile-development

[Click this link to see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPrZ.png)

please I need help how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So this worked for me.. cause I tried what someone suggested here on Stack Overflow. My laptop's display settings was set to 150%, which is recommended (according to my laptop settings), and I changed it to **125%** and it fixed the problem. Everything else on my screen turned a little bit smaller but it worked. I hope this helps someone else who ever encounters the same problem I had.